# OpenERP V7 - How to clear a parent field content after On_Change was trigger in widget="one2many_list"

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8

I am writing a customize Lab Test module in OpenERP V7. The rough idea was described in [OpenERP 7 - Create auto log message in "Log a Note" field as history log record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37935843/openerp-7-create-auto-log-message-in-log-a-note-field-as-history-log-record/37969084#37969084).

How could i achieve the step 2 where any changes in any field of the  one2many_list fields will trigger a function to clear the text in my "Reason For Change"(ROC) field which is the parent field?

Follow would be my example:

```py
'note_change': fields.text('Reason For Change',required=True),
'lab_lines': fields.one2many('test.lab', 'lab_id', 'Lab Lines'),
'lab_id': fields.many2one('test.lab', 'Parent Lab', ondelete='cascade', select=True), 
'product_name': fields.char('Product Name', size=64),
'product_id': fields.many2one('product.product', 'Product'),
```

The relavant functions in py would be:

```py
def onchange_product_id(self, cr, uid, ids, product_id, name, context=None):
    b_flags = False           
    if product_id:
        prod = self.pool.get('product.product').browse(cr, uid, product_id, context=context)
        res_id = context.get('test', False)
        if res_id:                
            """
            @TO trigger the function to set reason for change as empty                 
            """
            b_flags = True
            self.fnct_trigger_onchange(cr,uid,res_id,b_flags,context)               
        else:
            #other code here         

        warning = { 'title': 'Warning!',
                    'message' : 'Please enter reason for changes.',
                  }

        return {'value': {'product_name': prod.name, 'product_uom': prod.uom_id.id, 'product_std_cost': prod.standard_price},
                'warning': warning,
                }
    return {}
```

My write object function here:

```py
def fnct_trigger_onchange(self,cr,uid,ids,b_flags,context=None):
        """
        @if b_flags is true means onchange function in this object was triggered
        @if b_flags is false means onchange function in this object was not triggered
        """
        res = {} 

        """
        @if b_flags is true then reset the Note Change field to empty
        """
        if b_flags:
            lab_obj= self.pool.get('test.lab')
            strResetEmpty=" "
            if not isinstance(ids, list):
                ids = [ids]

            res_vals = {'note_change':strResetEmpty
                        }
            lab_obj.write(cr, uid, ids, res_vals, context=context)           

        return res
```

My XML here:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <form string="lab_form_view" version="7.0">    
   <notebook>
   <page string="Lab Products">
          <field name="lab_lines" widget="one2many_list" context="{'test':active_id}" >
             <tree string="Components" editable="bottom">                                            
                    <field name="product_id" required="1" context="{'default_supply_method':'produce'}" on_change="onchange_product_id(product_id, product_name, context)" />
                    <field name="product_name" invisible="1"/>                                    
              </tree>
          </field>                                                  
     </page>
     </notebook>

     <group colspan="4" string= "Remark Notes">
               <field name="note_change" />                   
     </group>
     </form>
```

Through this i can trigger the write object function in fnct_trigger_onchange when selecting new product in one2many list to clear my clear text content in ROC field. However this is not yet what i want, the problem of my current code is  the text (in ROC field) was cleared at background but not present/reflected in user view. The user still saw the old text even it actually was cleared.

I wish to achieve what as on_change method done where once user select product, the ROC field will immediately empty. How can i do that? Can anyone help me on this? Thanks !!